# Remove text labels of variables on diagonal corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

How can I remove text labels from diagonal **only** on `corrplot`?

```
corrplot(my_correlation_matrix1,
         method = "color",                                    
         type = "lower",                                      
         tl.col = "black",                                    
         tl.cex = 0.6,                                        
         tl.srt = 45)

corrplot(my_correlation_matrix2,
         method = "color",                                    
         type = "lower",                                      
         tl.col = "black",                                    
         tl.cex = 0.6,                                        
         tl.srt = 45,
         add = T)
```

Since I'm using `add = T`, the 2 `corrplot`s are merged in one plot. But because they have values on the diagonal, they are overlapping. How can this be fixed?

What I'm trying to do, is merge 2-corrplots-in-1. Two different studies for the same set of values. `Upper triangular` is `measurement A` and `lower` is `measurement B`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems here.  Because you do not provide your correlation matrices,  we cannot run your code to see exactly what you see.   Please add the correlation matrices to the question using `dput(my_correlation_matrix1)` and `dput(my_correlation_matrix2)`.      Also,  in your example code, both matrices are printed with `type = "lower"`. I think that you wanted one of them to be "upper".

The tl.xxx series of parameters to `corrplot` control all of the text labels. I don't think that you can control those on the diagonal separately. However, I think that you can get what you want without much work. Just create and plot a full matrix that has the values that you want.

```
merged_corr_matrix = my_correlation_matrix1
LT = lower.tri(merged_corr_matrix)
merged_corr_matrix[LT] = my_correlation_matrix2[LT]

corrplot(merged_corr_matrix,
     method = "color",                                    
     tl.col = "black",                                    
     tl.cex = 0.6,                                        
     tl.srt = 45)
```